# ajax not getting response from json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two cascading drop down lists in ASP.NET with MVC4. I am using ajax call to invoke the Json method from Controller. Json method is returning set of values which i needed for the drop down list but its not coming in ajax. Its always showing error message that failed to load the data.

Following is the code for Ajax call

```
 $("#countryname").change(function () {

        if ($("#countryname").val() != "Please select") {
            var options = {};
            options.url = "/ServeEasy/GetStates";
            options.type = "GET";
            //options.data = JSON.stringify({ countryID: $("#countryname").val() });
            options.data = { countryID: $("#countryname").val() };
            //alert($("#countryname").val());
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            debugger;
            options.success = function (slist) {
                $("#statename").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < slist.length; i++) {
                    $("#statename").append("<option>" + slist[i] + "</option>");
                }
                $("#statename").prop("disabled", false);
            };
            options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving states!"); };
            $.ajax(options);
        }            
        else {
            $("#statename").empty();
            $("#statename").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

and the Json method is as the following

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetStates(string countryID)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> StateList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        IEnumerable<FOSEntities.State> slist = new List<FOSEntities.State>();
        slist = serveEasyServices.GetStateByCountry(countryID);
        return Json(slist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return Json(new { slist = slist }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: do you get any errors in developers tool?

Comment: are u able to get into the server side method?

Comment: @Zaki No errors showing in developer tool.

Comment: @iJay Yeah i am able to get into the server side method and the    slist is has the values to display in drop down list

Comment: are u getting the slist on client side too

Comment: your code is working for me.how many data you get in `slist`.

Comment: @Jaimin total 4 is there.

Comment: @iJay its not geting on client side thats the problem. It always showing the message "Error retrieving states!"

Comment: @SajnaAli i just post demo with your code i hope it may help you.and if you have any concern let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, This is just example

```
 $("#CustomerId").change(function () {
      var Id = $("#CustomerId").val();
      var options = {};
            options.url = '@Url.Action("GetCustomerNameWithId", "Test")';
            options.type = "GET";
            //options.data = JSON.stringify({ countryID: $("#countryname").val() });
            options.data = { CustomerNameId: Id };
            //alert($("#countryname").val());
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            options.success = function (listItems) {
                $("#CustomerNameId").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
                    $("#CustomerNameId").append('<option value="' + listItems[i].Value + '">' + listItems[i].Text + '</option>');
                }
            };
            options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving states!"); };
            $.ajax(options);
        });

   @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerNameID, "--Select--")
   @Html.DropDownList("CustomerNameId", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text"), "-- Select --")
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetCustomerNameWithId(string CustomerNameId)
{
 int _CustomerNameId = 0;
 int.TryParse(CustomerNameId, out _CustomerNameId);
 var listItems = GetCustomerNameId(_CustomerNameId).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.CID.ToString(), Text = s.CustomerName }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
 return Json(listItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

 public List<Customer> GetCustomerNameId(int CustomerNameId)
 {
   // Customer cascade DropDown
   using (dataDataContext _context = new dataDataContext())
   {
    return (from c in _context.Customers
            where c.CID == CustomerNameId
            select c).ToList();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But i am geting error on GetCustomerNameID method. And I wrote the methods to fetch the data from the State table so is this needed to write the code like this? That method is working properly only the problem is the items geting in     slist is not coming in ajax

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following changes and it worked!!

On Json method, the following changes

```
public JsonResult GetStates(string countryID)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> StateList = new List<SelectListItem>();   
        var slist = serveEasyServices.GetStateByCountry(countryID).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.StateID.ToString(), Text = s.State }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
        return Json(slist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and on Ajax

```
$("#countryname").change(function () {
        var Id = $("#countryname").val();
        if ($("#countryname").val() != "Please select") {
            var options = {};
            options.url = '@Url.Action("GetStates", "ServeEasy")'; 
            options.type = "GET";                
            options.data = { countryID: Id };
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            debugger;
            options.success = function (slist) {
                $("#statename").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < slist.length; i++) {                      
                    $("#statename").append('<option value="' + slist[i].Value + '">' + slist[i].Text + '</option>');
                }
                $("#statename").prop("disabled", false);
            };
            options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving states!"); };
            $.ajax(options);
        }            
        else {
            $("#statename").empty();
            $("#statename").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

@Jaimin Thank you so much for your help :)